# gdb gef not working after fresh compilation of gdb 12.1 and gef 2022.06

Tags: gdbserver, gdb-python

I recently compiled gdb to 12.1 and attempted to install gef via the following cmd bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://gef.blah.cat/sh)"

the code on line 52 in the image is **import abc**

the screenshot can be viewed here https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuGk7.png

Comment: Did you build gdb with python support?

Answer (score -1):

try to install gdb because you maybe running gdb-min

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).